# The signature is invalid when applying new Aspose.Words.lic and Aspose.Cells.lic

Tags: aspose, aspose.words, aspose-cells

We have renewed the "Aspose.Cells.lic" and "Aspose.Words.lic"
the steps that we did:

1. we have downloaded the files.
2. we replaced the new files with the old ones, but we noticed that the naming of the new files is different, before we had "Aspose.Cells.lic" and "Aspose.Words.lic" , but now we got files with "Java" and the license version is different

This is the message that we got when we applied the files:
**The signature is invalid.java.lang.IllegalStateException: The signature is invalid.**

the steps that we did:

1. we have downloaded the files.
2. we replaced the new files with the old ones, but we noticed that the naming of the new files is different, before we had "Aspose.Cells.lic" and "Aspose.Words.lic" , but now we got files with "Java" and the license version is different

Comment: The question is answered in Aspose.Words support forum https://forum.aspose.com/t/how-to-apply-new-licenses/255354/2

Comment: @AlexeyNoskov thanks, we also replied on the support forum

Comment: @AlexeyNoskov  https://forum.aspose.com/t/how-to-apply-new-licenses/255354

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note, new licenses are signed with SHA256 but older ones were signed with SHA1. Either you may use your older license(s) with the old versions of Aspose libraries and newer license(s) with the new versions of Aspose. Or you may contact [relevant team](https://forum.aspose.com/c/purchase/6) to get updated licenses (e.g. signed with sha1) which can work with both newer and older versions.

PS. I am working as Support developer/Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Can you please help us further with this matter through Webex call?

Comment: We are sorry but we do not handle technical queries or issues via net meetings. As suggested, please contact relevant team to get updated licenses. Alternatively, you may access us via dedicated forums (https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9) if you still have queries or issues.